# Serialize/Encrypt/Transmit Web Form Data to Web Service

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, serialization, encryption

I have an ASP.NET 1.1 form gathering data on a public-facing site, within a DMZ. The data is represented by a serializable class. My problem is that I need to serialize, encrypt and transmit the data to a Web Service running on an internal server - the service logic should then decrypt and deserialize the data before writing the XML to a shared folder.

Can someone point me in the right direction? What's the most straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to use SSL to secure the Web Service on the internal server? This would seem to offer the protection you require.

If you don't have SSL, you will want to [serialize the class to XML](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813) and then encrypt it. Then decrypt to the serialized XML format. You could then [deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize(VS.71).aspx) the XML files created on the share.

Encryption is fairly straightforward to program because you have a string of XML that you want to encrypt and decrypt. The challenge is with the choice of the encryption algorithm and the storage of encryption keys. You should read up on [symmetric](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=symmetric+encryption+c%23&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) and [assymetric](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=assymetric+encryption+c%23&aq=f&aqi=m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) encryption. If the key is exposed then an attacker can easily decrypt your data. Use file permissions to tightly control access.

The simplest option is to use symmetric keys and store the keys on the both ends. There are a number of [examples](http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx) and [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa302405) out there.

Comment: Yes, I can use SSL to go from DMZ to internal server - presumably I'm okay using our own CA for this. Actually, don't need to deserialize, can leave it in folder as XML file. What data type do I use to pass the serialized object to the Web Service?

Comment: Your own CA should suffice, but protecting your certificates etc is similar to protecting encryption keys.

Someone will probably disagree but I would say just pass over the XML as a string if you simply need to get it across the wire. You are probably going to add some dev time on by trying to model the service to match the XML data that you want to pass over.

Comment: Brian, could you expand a little on "protecting your certificates"? Thanks :)

Comment: Basically being careful where you store them and making sure only required users have permissions to access. I've seen developers being careless and leaving key files like this lying around in directories which could be accessed by others.

Comment: Thank Brian - marked as answer and an up vote for Irish Engineering ;-)